# NullPointerExceptio When Resume Fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have a two fragments inside ViewPager. These fragments have timers that call asyncs for the WS. I stop and resume the timer in OnResume and just stop it in OnPause. Sometimes, in S4 smartphone, Im having the following error:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at futbol.app.fragment.FragmentUsuariosConectados$3.run(FragmentUsuariosConectados.java:220)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are the lines reported in the log, they are inside a tvRegistrados.post:

```
Line 219:   BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = convertViewToDrawable(
Line 220:                           getActivity(), tvRegistrados);
```

This is my entire Fragment class

```
public class FragmentUsuariosConectados extends Fragment {

    private View view = null;

    private FragmentActivity activity;

    private JSONObject obj;

    private Boolean isTimeToPrint;

    private Boolean isWsFinished;

    private UsuariosConectadosList usuariosList;

    private final static int DELAY_TIME = 540000;

    private Timer timer;

    public FragmentUsuariosConectados newInstance() {
        FragmentUsuariosConectados f = new FragmentUsuariosConectados();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        isTimeToPrint = false;
        timer = new Timer();
        isWsFinished = false;
        getFragmentActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stopTimer();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        resumeTimer();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usuarios_conectados,
                container, false);

        // Realiza una espera, para que al menu lateral le de tiempo de cerrarse
        // antes de pintar la pantalla
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                isTimeToPrint = true;
                if (isWsFinished && isTimeToPrint) {

                    onDrawScreen();
                    Log.e("DELAY", "ENTRA");
                }
            }

        }, Constantes.TIME_DELAY);

        return view;
    }

    public class WSGet extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        // URL del ws
        private String url;
        private WSController ws;

        public WSGet(String url) {
            this.url = url;
            this.ws = new WSController();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.i("WSGET", "Chat");
            obj = ws.getWS(getActivity(), url);

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            if (obj != null)
                usuariosList = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(),
                        UsuariosConectadosList.class);

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            isWsFinished = true;
            if (isWsFinished && isTimeToPrint) {

                onDrawScreen();

            }

        }

    }

    private void onDrawScreen() {

        try {
            if (getFragmentActivity() != null && view != null) {

                TextView tvCompartir = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_invitar);
                tvCompartir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        new CompartirDialog(getActivity()).show();

                    }
                });

                if (usuariosList != null && usuariosList.getError() != null
                        && usuariosList.getError().getCodError().equals(0)) {

                    loadUsuarios();

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void loadUsuarios() {

        UsuariosConectados usuariosConectados = usuariosList.getRespuesta();
        final List<Usuario> registradosList = usuariosConectados.getUsuarios();

        if (registradosList != null) {

            TextView tvNumConectados = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_num_conectados);
            tvNumConectados.setText(registradosList.size() + "");

            final TextView tvRegistrados = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.usuarios_registrados);
            if (!registradosList.isEmpty())
                tvRegistrados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final List<BitmapDrawable> bitmapList = new ArrayList<BitmapDrawable>();
            tvRegistrados.post(new Runnable() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i < registradosList.size(); i++) {

                        String nick = registradosList.get(i).getNick();
                        tvRegistrados.setText(nick);
                        tvRegistrados
                                .setBackgroundDrawable(getFragmentActivity()
                                        .getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(
                                                R.drawable.shape_bg_usuario_registrado));

                        try {

                                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = convertViewToDrawable(
                                        getFragmentActivity(), tvRegistrados);
                                bitmapList.add(bitmapDrawable);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    SpannableStringBuilder sStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < bitmapList.size(); i++) {

                        Spannable wordSpan = new SpannableString("1" + " ");

                        BitmapDrawable bd = bitmapList.get(i);
                        bd.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (bd.getIntrinsicWidth()),
                                (int) (bd.getIntrinsicHeight()));
                        wordSpan.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), 0, 1,
                                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                        sStringBuilder.append(wordSpan);

                    }

                        tvRegistrados.setText(sStringBuilder);
                        tvRegistrados.setBackgroundColor(getFragmentActivity()
                                .getResources().getColor(
                                        android.R.color.transparent));


                }
            });

        }

        Integer numInvitados = 0;
        if (usuariosConectados.getNumInvitados() != null) {
            numInvitados = usuariosConectados.getNumInvitados();
        }
        TextView tvInvitados = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_usuarios_invitados);
        tvInvitados.setText(numInvitados.toString());

    }

    public class WSTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("TIMER WS", "EXECUTE");

            if (getFragmentActivity() != null) {

                // Login periodico del usuario en el chat
                Usuario usuario = UtilPreferencias
                        .getUsuario(getFragmentActivity());
                if (usuario != null) {
                    Usuario registrado = new Usuario();
                    registrado.setNick(usuario.getNick());
                    registrado.setPassword(usuario.getPassword());
                    new WSLogin(registrado).execute();
                } else {
                    Usuario invitado = new Usuario();
                    String uuid = UtilPreferencias
                            .getUuid(getFragmentActivity());
                    invitado.setUuid(uuid);
                    new WSLogin(invitado).execute();
                }

                // Obtiene los conectados
                new WSGet(Webservices.URL_BASE
                        + Webservices.USUARIOS_CONECTADOS
                        + futbol.app.constante.Stylo.ID_EQUIPO).execute();

            }
        }

    }

    public class WSLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        // URL del ws
        private String url;
        private WSController ws;
        private Usuario usuario;

        public WSLogin(Usuario usuario) {

            this.ws = new WSController();
            if (usuario.getNick() != null && !usuario.getNick().equals(""))
                this.url = Webservices.URL_BASE + Webservices.USUARIO_LOGIN;
            else
                this.url = Webservices.URL_BASE + Webservices.USUARIO_INVITADO;
            this.usuario = usuario;
            this.usuario.setIdEquipo(futbol.app.constante.Stylo.ID_EQUIPO);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.i("WSLOGIN", "Login");

            obj = ws.postWS(getFragmentActivity(), url, usuario);

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }

    }

    public static BitmapDrawable convertViewToDrawable(Context context,
            View view) {
        int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.measure(spec, spec);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
        view.draw(c);
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap cacheBmp = view.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), viewBmp);

    }

    public FragmentActivity getFragmentActivity() {

        if (activity == null) {
            activity = this.getActivity();
        }
        return activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        stopTimer();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopTimer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public Timer getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public void stopTimer() {

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    public void resumeTimer() {
        stopTimer();
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            // Hace autologin cada 9 min.
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new WSTimerTask(), 0, DELAY_TIME);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what exact line of code is at line 220 in `FragmentUsuariosConectados`?

Comment: this:  
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = convertViewToDrawable(      getActivity(), tvRegistrados);

Comment: I edited the main post to make it more clear

Comment: ok, i show my entire fragment now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition.

Your fragment has been detached from its parent Activity (maybe because the user has navigated away from it?) while your AsyncTask was still running.

You should guard against this by checking (getActivity() == null) before proceeding any further.